# Load Separate xib view controller into Storyboard navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 storyboards, I have common screen for both storyboards. I have created it as a separate view controller with xib. I want to load it in between storyboard screens.

Answer (score 2):

You can load VC from Nib file very easily. try the code below :

```
func presentMyViewController() {
    let myVC = MainViewController(nibName:"MyViewController", bundle:nil)
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(myVC, true);
    // you could present it another way, such as:
    // self.presentViewController(myVC, true, nil)
}
```

Edit : As per comment I don't think that we can directly load xib from story-board but if we need to navigate to xib then you can try above code or else you can also add child view controller directly on viewcontroller.

Comment: The question is how to do it in a storyboard, not the code.

Comment: Here the question is not clear first of all and second is before downvoting any reply you should consider to give acknowledgment by posting the comment. @SrđanStanić

Comment: I'm sorry, I was too quick to downvote. Can you please edit your answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: Edited. asking question with proper description will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below:

You can override the loadview() method in class.

```
public class MyViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyViewController", owner: self, options: [:])
    }

   //your stuff here...

}
```

Assumes of course your XIB is `MyViewController.xib`. Adjust to suit.

edit: also assumes you've correctly set up the files owner references in the XIB (i.e. to the view controller in question).